# How to handle Jmeter tests

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0, dynamic-values

Measuring the load time of an ( web-based application)

When a user clicks on a link, the web-based Application sends a Request to the server

I have tried to take the above post request and loop it under While loop controller  with a condition.
But the while loops just loops forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are following possible origins for these `requestId` dynamic variable:

1. It may be present in response URL as the result of a [redirection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections)
2. It may be present in response [headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers)
3. It may be present in response body
4. It is generated on the client side (browser) using JavaScript

In first 3 cases you need to correlate the value using a suitable [post-processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors), in 4th case you need to replicate the JavaScript code which is generating the value using [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) and [Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor)

---

We cannot comment anything on your While Controller issue apart from very obvious statement that the While Controller will execute its child(ren) until the [variable or function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) which you put in the "Condition" are resolves to `true`, the evaluation result including any nested variables can be observed using i.e. [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler)